# Wagtail redirect max length too short

Tags: django, wagtail

Our migration into Wagtail involves creating redirects for very long urls e.g. urls in Arabic. These do not seem to be supported by the Wagtail redirects system. Any workarounds for this?

Migration script error:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(255)
```

Database console error:

```
db_1     | 2018-08-24 13:19:06.000 UTC [134] ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255)
db_1     | 2018-08-24 13:19:06.000 UTC [134] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "wagtailredirects_redirect" ("old_path", "site_id", "is_permanent", "redirect_page_id", "redirect_link") VALUES ('https://www.opendemocracy.net/5050/atiaf-zaid-alwazir/%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A7-%D9%8A%D8%B2%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%82-%D8%B7%D9%88%D9%8A%D9%84%D8%A7-%E2%80%93-%D8%A8%D9%82%D9%84%D9%85-%D8%A3%D8%B7%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%81-%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B1', 1, true, 9528, '') RETURNING "wagtailredirects_redirect"."id"
```

(note: even removing the domain from the url still leaves us with a utf-8 string of 257, which is too long)

Comment: Hopefully this doesn't sound too glib - but you'll likely have to modify the base Wagtail code - up the max length, there's likely somewhere a redirects model.

Comment: Would strongly prefer not to run a forked version of Wagtail. But this is an option, thank you.

Comment: No worries, I would certainly advise against this. Perhaps there must be a way to inherit and extend from the base `Redirect` model...?

Comment: I would suggest you open this as an issue on the Wagtail issue tracker. This length limit looks a bit arbitrary, and I'm sure you could make the case for it to be raised or removed.

Comment: The current limit is set at https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/contrib/redirects/models.py#L8

Interestingly, the limit in Django's redirect app is even lower:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/redirects/models.py

Django requires a `max_length` argument for `Charfield`s. There's an 8 year old discussion about this:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14094

I guess there are two options for dealing with this in Wagtail: increase the max_length, or convert it to a TextField, which may have performance implications on some backends?

Comment: @tomd Do you think it's a good idea to request this as a permanent change to Wagtail core?

Comment: @KindOfGuy yes I think so. Keeping `CharField` and increasing max_length to 500 feels like a flawed but safe approach. Feel free to discuss with me and others on Slack at https://wagtail.io/slack/